# How to deploy a node-angular app on public ip?

Tags: node.js, angular, ip, localhost, host

I have an angular 4 app as front-end and a node app as my server side. and I have a local server with 192.168.x.y IP. i run my node app on 192.168.x.y:3000. I have a public id 151.233.t.z! in my angular app package.json, I used `ng serve --port 8080 --host 192.168.x.y --public 151.233.t.z`. and in my .angular-cli.json is used :

```
 "defaults": {
"styleExt": "scss",
"component": {},
"serve" : {
  "host" : "151.233.t.z",
  "port": 8080
}
```

and in my HTTP services in angular, I send my HTTP requests to 192.168.x.y:3000.
now when I run my apps, I can run the whole app on my local system, but I cant connect to the backend (for login) when I try with IP out of my local server IP! also I have a database on this server with IP : 192.168.x.m

Comment: You need to use public IP(`151.233.t.z`) for front-end and back-end as well

Comment: @ArifKhan and it doesn't matter that my server side is running on 192.1683.x.y:3000?

Comment: You need to run your back-end application on public IP or use the reverse proxy for back-end

Comment: @ArifKhan sorry can you help me about reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have no changes in angular cli.When you create a build include

```
      <base href="/">
```

this line in index.html.

Dist folder and main file in  node place on same location after that you will start pm2 then after open in browser .it's working.

Comment: but i don't know how to run my app on public id when i'm using dist folder.

Comment: Upload node application on server with dist folder.And using this command pm2 start filename that you are using strart node server on localhost

Comment: I used this and I'm running my node file in pm2 but as I told, I have an angular service which is using HTTP requests, I cannot access the localhost because my angular is running on public IP

Comment: I think you want access localhost node api from public ip where angular project run.